# Error when using PHP to modify database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm trying to insert a bunch of data into a database, but I am having this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1

Here are my two files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Insert new Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="insert_page.php" method="get">
              New Page Name:<br>
              <input type="text" name="pagename">
              <input type="submit" value="Insert" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is insert_page.html, it's simply a text box and a button where the user can choose the new name for a new page to be entered in the database.

Now, here's the PHP being called when the button is pressed

```
<?php

        $servername = "db.ist.utl.pt";
        $username = "ist178349";
        $password = "getrekt";
        $dbname = "ist178349";
        $pagename = $_POST['pagename'];

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO pagina (userid, pagecounter, nome, idseq, ativa)
            VALUES (78349, 95002, " + $pagename + ",1151988, true)";

            // use exec() because no results are returned
            $conn->exec($sql);

            echo "New record created successfully";
            }

        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
            }
        $conn = null;
?>
```

However, I am getting that error, which I can't really understand. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `+` is for concatenation in JavaScript, `.` is what you should use in PHP.

Comment: You may also need single quotations around $pagename since I assume it is a string. ....95002, '".$pagename."', 1151988...

Comment: @DanilaHanchar you're suggesting code edits which may go against what the OP intended or are not improving the question. In some cases you may be doing harm. If you'd like to post your edits as answers you're free to do so.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think flagging will put a damper on all this Sam.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) as well. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix your query that contains `+` use `.` or leave it out and use single quote, that's acceptable in PHP sql query string.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO pagina (userid, pagecounter, nome, idseq, ativa)
        VALUES (78349, 95002, '$pagename', 1151988, true)";
```

Comment: That was it, thanks.